# How to auto prompt password on startup for password protected BitLocker Drive

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I have a BitLocker Drive (a partition on my internal hard drive) protected with a password. I don't want to turn on auto-unlock but I would like to be prompted for the password on Windows 10 startup.

How can I achieve this?

Currently, I open the file explorer every time and double click that particular partition to be prompted to enter my password. But this is quite cumbersome.

Comment: The only password you could be entering at startup is the recovery key which is a really long string of numbers. I'm pretty sure you don't want to enter those. Your harddisk is always locked until windows unlocks it to boot from it using TPM. It is a safe way and makes sure the entire computer must be used to get to the files, not just the harddisk. So... consider setting up a BIOS boot-up password instead.

Comment: Thanks but it's not my primary partition with the system files. It's an additional partition for data. I am looking for being prompted right after Windows is ready to use.

Comment: What you want should be possible using a script that asks for the password and then calls `manage-bde -unlock D: -password <entered password>` That script could then be added to autostart folder.